# Почему не работает цикл while (для начинающих)?

Tags: python, циклы

Самостоятельно изучаю Питон по лекциям и примерам в интернет.
Ниже пример цикла, который я пытаюсь повторить.

Но у меня не появляются значения 5,7,9... Что не так?

```
i = 5
while i < 15:
    print(i)
    i = i + 2
```

Comment: Скажите, на пустой строке вы добавляли отступ в 4 пробела, или нажали enter на **пустой** строке?

Comment: установите PyCharm , будет проще осваивать и подобных ошибок не будет. на ютубе есть ролики по установке и настройке.

Comment: Евгений, нет не добавляла отступы. Нажимала enter на пустой строке, но сейчас все получилось. Просто надо было нажать enter 2 раза. Сначала появляется пустая строка с тремя точками, затем столбец с числами. Это меня и сбило. Я не получила столбца с числами сразу. Просто Python открыла третий раз с нуля. Всё новое. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Возможная причина этой проблемы - отступ в 4 пробела на пустых строках (по скрину это понять довольно трудно)
Приведу пример.

---

Проблемный вариант:

```py
>>> i=5
>>> while i<15:
...    print (i)
...    i=i+2
...    #
...    #
...    # < тут есть 4 пробела
```

Решается довольно просто: пробелы в пустой строке нужно ставить в соответствие с **внешним** уровнем:

```py
>>> i=5
>>> while i<15:
...    print (i)
...    i=i+2
... # < тут нет пробелов
5
7
9
11
13
>>>
```